# Raise event after distributed call has refreshed cache in umbraco 7

Tags: events, load-balancing, umbraco7

Is there a built-in way to raise an event on a load-balanced server in umbraco 7.

I would like to hook into the event-pipeline on the load-balanced server once the editor-server has finished clearing caches as a distributed call.

The reason for this is that I need to clear some custom caches based on the newly published content and would like to avoid building my own solution for this if there already is an event for this type of functionality.

I have already hooked up to these events:

`Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService.Created`
`Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService.Saved`
`Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService.Publishing`
`Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService.Published`

None of these seem to fire on the load-balanced servers, only on the editor-server.
Publishing of normal content works as intended with the distributedcalls configuration in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a very similar need with custom caches, and have success with these events:

`umbraco.content.AfterRefreshContent`
`umbraco.content.AfterUpdateDocumentCache`
`umbraco.content.AfterClearDocumentCache`

Comment: it seems that these events use the obsolete umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document

Comment: That's true, however they're in active use by Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.RoutesCache.ResolutionFrozen() so I fear they're the best we've got.

The other down-side of the events is that they're too coarse-grained, not containing any useful payload which indicates *what* content has been updated. This means that, in my implementation, I need to invalidate my entire cache in response to these events, rather than intelligently invalidating portions of the cache which are required.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but will continue my search for an optimal solution. Thanks